# how do I decouple my domain handler from package level definitions

Tags: go, struct, interface

I have a basic handler, that uses an 3rd party package `messager`.

The package returns a concrete struct of `messager.Shape` provided by a `Get` method.

messager.go

```
type Shape struct {
    Value struct {
        Type   string
        Other  int
        Active bool
    }
    Markers struct {
        Range int
        Name  string
    }
    ID string
}

...

func (m *Messager) Get(ID string) (Shape, error) {
    ...
}
```

handler.go

```
package handler

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/fake/message"
)

type Getter interface {
    Get(ID string) (messager.Shape, error)
}

type Handler struct {
    messager Getter
}

func NewHandler(g Getter) *Handler {
    return &Handler{ messager: g }
}

func (h *Handler) DoSomething() {
    fmt.Println(h.messager.Get("some-id").Value.Type)
}
```

The handler only really cares that something can provide a struct with a matching nested `Value.Type` string.

I attempted defining a struct for the interface that wanted just:

```
type ValueType struct {
    Value struct {
        Type string
    }
}

type Getter interface {
    Get(ID string) (ValueType, error)
}
```

but the compiler rejects it when creating a `NewHandler` as the `messager.Get` method type does not match the interface. What am I suppose to do here? Is it appropriate for my Handler to reference the package struct? Should the package not be returning something so definitive?

I appreciate the example is a bit contrived but just trying to work out what's correct.

Comment: If you only care about the one string, why not just return that? `Get(ID string) (string, error)`?

Comment: @Adrian definitely what I would do if I controlled this package, it's more a question of what do you do when you don't control it. Or even if I wrote such a package, how should it be done to be the most flexible it can be?

Comment: If you don't control the package then you have no choice in the matter and the question seems moot... can you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: I feel like having the interface there is a way to decouple my concerns, but if I can only use it in a manner that has to rely on something deeper in the package I'm trying to decouple from then feels like the interface becomes pointless. I'm really just asking if that's how it has to be, or if I'm missing some technique when defining interfaces?

Comment: Just having an interface doesn't decouple anything; interfaces as a feature allow for decoupled designs, but creating interfaces doesn't automatically mean the design is decoupled.